# How can I express just the last sum

Tags: awk

I want to see just last sum here, but it shows me everything.

```bash
awk '{print sum += $1} END {print sum}' file.dat
```

This is the output:

```
1.2
3.6
7.3
7.3
```

Comment: How is this Ubuntu-related? Seems like a good Stack Exchange question. (Hint: What do you expect the `print` statement in `(print sum +=$1}` to do?)

Comment: @user535733 It would be rather odd if we considered this question off-topic, because [shell scripting is on-topic here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic), and `awk` one-liners like this are clearly part of shell scripting. Furthermore, using external commands like `sed` and `awk` to process text line-by-line is the preferred practice in shell scripting; needlessly using shell builtins instead [is somewhat discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/11938). I, or someone else, can post an answer to this question, but do you want to?

Comment: @EliahKagan fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you want sums in `file.dat` added together and then print them out, the line should be:

```bsh
awk '{sum +=$1} END {print sum}' file.dat
```

Telling `awk` to print the `sum` every time you add a new value to `sum` makes it show each intermediate value, just as you have experienced.